# Custom keyword list for auto completion M-/?

Tags: completion, auto-complete-mode

I make use of <kbd>M-/</kbd> for auto-completion. Is it possible to supply a custom list of frequently used keywords (e.g. for a niche programming language) to be loaded at Emacs startup?

I could save the keywords into a separate file, and opening this file (together with the file I want to edit) will enable auto-completion of these keywords, but it's inconvenient if I have to do this every time I start Emacs.

Comment: You have a couple of built-in options for this. Probably the easiest one will be defining [abbrevs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Abbrevs.html)

Comment: What is `C-/` bound to? The question seems incomplete/unclear. Just what are you doing wrt auto-complete?

Comment: Sorry, I meant M-/, not C-/ ! It's the standard emacs command for "dynamic expansion". I corrected the question.